# Fill textbox using variable error object required

Tags: html, vbscript

Hi I am new to VB and I am encountering a problem where when trying to fill a textbox with a variable it keeps on going showing me Object required. below please find the code. The Search_for_Vehicle is a mehtod where the sCarReg is being filled.

```
sub loadtest()
response.write("Sub"+sCarReg)
Search_for_Vehicle(sCarReg)
txtCarReg.Text = sCarReg
end sub
```

loadtest

The problem is that it is showing me the following error

Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8'

Object required: 'sCarReg'

I am calling this method exactly at the bottom of the method  loadtest

Comment: How are you calling this sub?

Comment: loadtest exactly under the method

Comment: Is `sCarReg` declared globally?

Comment: yes i thing that it is generating this error because the textbox is not being found

Comment: You need `sCarReg` to declared globally, probably at the top as `Dim sCarReg` then if you change the value anywhere it will keep the value. or you can pass the value to `loadtest` like `sub loadtest(sCarReg) ..` and then call it as `loadsub('XXX')`